# Как сформировать либо исполняемый файл либо либу одного проекта, в зависимости от собираемого в qmake проекта

Tags: qt, qmake

Имеется Qt проект, состоящий из нескольких компонентов. Каждый компонент на выходе даёт исполняемый файл. В компоненте (далее comp0), над которым я работаю, требуется солидная часть кода из другого компонента (далее comp1), выдающего какие-то требуемые мне данные.

Вынести требуемый мне код в отдельную либу, которую смог бы использовать и comp0 и comp1, я не могу. Я хочу сформировать либу из comp1 и вызывать из него функцию, которая вернёт требуемые мне данные.

Сейчас добавил следующий код в `.pro` файл comp1:

```
SOME_PATH_TO_COMP0 = $$(SOME_PATH_TO_COMP0)
include($$SOME_PATH_TO_COMP0/comp.pri)

COMP1_TO_LIB {
    TEMPLATE = lib
    LIBNAME = Comp1
} else {
    TEMPLATE = app
}
```

, и создал в каталогах comp0 `comp.pri`, просто чтобы не бегать между `.pro` файлами и каталогами разных компонентов (изначально это казалось удобным):

```
isEmpty( COMP0_PRI ) {

win32 {
    CONFIG += embed_manifest_dll embed_manifest_exe
}

CONFIG += COMP1_TO_LIB

SOME_PATH_TO_COMP0= $$(SOME_PATH_TO_COMP0)      
DLLDESTDIR = $$SOME_PATH_TO_COMP0/bin

}
```

Теперь я могу собрать comp1 в исполняемый файл или либу, при этом каждый раз нужно лезть в `.pro` файл и комментить/анкомментить инклуд.

Вопрос: Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы при сборке comp1 всегда формировался исполняемый файл, а при сборке comp0 формировалась dll comp1, и как это реализовать? Возможно для данной ситуации есть иные пути решения, лучше пришедшего мне в голову, хотел бы услышать и про них (кроме выноса нужного мне кода в отдельную либу, этого делать нельзя).

Comment: В подобной ситуации, когда несколько прог шарят много кода между собой, я разбиваю его на подмодули и каждый подмодуль убираю в отдельный .pri файл. Это проще для понимания и для пересборки, но сама сборка идет чуть дольше. Не стал оформлять это в виде ответа так как технически это не ответ на поставленный вопрос. Но если это устраивает, распишу подробнее.

Comment: @BeardedBeaver Насколько я понимаю, Вы говорите о разбиении кода на логические части по каталогам, каждый из которых имеет своё .pri файл, по сути тот же .pro (пока не вникал в чём разница), и сборку этих кусков в одном главном .pro? Если так, то такой вариант, к сожалению, не подходит, я не могу вмешиваться в компонент другой команды, кроме незначительных изменений главного .pro и создания функции на экспорт с выдачей нужных мне данных. Если идею понял неверно, то, конечно, хотелось бы почитать поподробнее, знания лишними не бывают:)

Comment: @BeardedBeaver На текущий момент я пришёл к тому, что для `comp0` был создан .pro `subdirs`, включающий в `SUBDIRS` каталог `comp1` и `comp0`, при сборке через который `comp1` генерит либу, засчёт добавления `DEFINES`. Т.к. такой способ не работает, пытался воспользоваться советом из [ссылка](https://wiki.qt.io/QMake-top-level-srcdir-and-builddir), однако представленное решение (у меня Qt 5.8, win) для меня не работает. Весь код на работе и показать что я там накрутил сейча не могу. Недеюсь завтра смогу разобраться и опубликовать ответ.

Comment: Так вам не обязательно вмешиваться в этот код, вы просто, условно говоря, делаете pull этого сабмодуля (его даже можно оформить как submodule) в git и просто собираете его как часть своего кода, но не трогая сам код. Хотя вариант с библиотекой конечно красивее, но тут у меня опыта мало пока, не подскажу.

Comment: @BeardedBeaver В таком случае, полагаю, я не понимаю о чём идёт речь, хотелось бы узнать поподробнее. Обязателен ли для этого git? У нас используется svn и я не уверен, предоставляет ли он требуемый функционал. Также не понял, Вы предлагаете выцепить нужный мне код, по сути добавив в мой компонент? Если так, то что будет при внесении изменений в код его разработчиками? Например, был добавлен новый класс, которого у меня нет, мне нужно будет его подцепить? Если так, это накладывает лишние обязательства на разработчиков модуля.

Comment: я не очень знаком с svn, но даже в случае библиотеки при добавлении нового класса вам нужно будет вытянуть обновленную библиотеку и новые h файлы, что тоже наложит обязательства на разработчиков модуля

Comment: @BeardedBeaver В моём представлении, если мне удастся реализовать задумку и собирать либу `comp1` при сборке своего компонента, мне ни мне, ни разработчикам того модуля не придётся производить лишних действий, т.к. всё будет автоматизированно и мне останется лишь спулить новую версию их компонента и запустить сборку, что намного проще выцепливания отдельных хедеров и исходников. Так или иначе, думаю мне будет полезно узнать о Вашем методе, может я и не смогу применить его для текущей задачи, но оно пригодится в дальнейшем

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93652/discussion-between-bearded-beaver-and-andrew-ruzavin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, я пришёл к следующему решению:

Мною был создан отдельный `comp1_lib.pro` файл, целиком копирующий `comp1.pro`, с той лишь разницей, что в `comp1.pro` осталось `TEMPLATE = app`, а в `comp1_lib.pro` он был заменён на:

```
SOME_PATH_TO_COMP0 = $$(SOME_PATH_TO_COMP0)
include($$SOME_PATH_TO_COMP0/comp1.pri)

TEMPLATE = lib
LIBNAME = Comp1
```

Код `comp1.pri` остался прежним, лишь убрал `CONFIG`:

```
isEmpty( COMP1_PRI ) {

win32 {
    CONFIG += embed_manifest_dll embed_manifest_exe
}

SOME_PATH_TO_COMP0= $$(SOME_PATH_TO_COMP0)      
DLLDESTDIR = $$SOME_PATH_TO_COMP0/bin

}
```

`comp1.pri` целесообразно добавить в `comp0.pro` следующим образом `OTHER_FILES += comp1.pri`.

Иерархия выглядит примерно таким образом:

```
comp0:
    comp0.pro
    comp1.pri
    //файлы кода
comp1:
    comp1.pro
    comp1_lib.pro
    //файлы кода
```

Теперь, посредством `comp1.pri`, я смогу легко вносить некоторые изменения в `comp1_lib.pro`, например сменить путь к расположению сгенерированной либы, без необходимости лезть в каталоги `comp1`. К сожалению, при добавлении новых файлов в `comp1`, мне нужно будет самому править `comp1_lib.pro`, либо просить разработчиков внести соответствующие изменения в этот `.pro` файл. Позже стоит добиться вынесения всех файлов из `comp1.pro` в отдельный `pri` файл и просто инклудить его в `comp1.pro` и `comp1_lib.pro`.